# nodejs socket.io security and public data

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I am building an app using nodeJS and socket.io and I have some questions related to socket.io and its security:

1)I am curious if the socket.id of each connection represents data that can be read by other people (can a hacker get a list of all the socket.id of all the users connected to the websocket server)?
Does this depend if the connection is done through SSL or not?

2)Can an attacker change his socket.id and if he matches the id of another socket will the matched socket become disconnected? If not, will the attacker at least be notified that he got a match?

3)Once a socket.id has been used for a handshake, can it be reused by an attacker if the client disconnects for a few seconds? Or is each socket.id unique and non-reusable?